# http.client.IncompleteRead error in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, http.client

I'm trying to scrape a [really long web page](https://www.worldcubeassociation.org/results/events.php?eventId=222&regionId=&years=&show=All%2BPersons&average=Average) with beautifulsoup4 and python3. Due to the size of the website, `http.client` throws me an error when I try to search for something in the website:

> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 456, in read return self._readall_chunked()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 570, in _readall_chunked raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
>   http.client.IncompleteRead: **IncompleteRead(16109 bytes read)**

Is there any way to get around this error?

Comment: The [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) library is pretty low-level. I believe you can solve this by manually reading and assembling the chunks, but it's kind of a pain. If possible, it would be much easier to switch to `requests` if you can use a third-party library, or `urllib` if you can't. (In fact, it even says this right at the top of the docs…) Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: If you _do_ need to stick with `http.client`, and you want us to show how to fix your code, you're going to have to give us the relevant code (and ideally a [mcve], not just a snippet from a larger program that can't be run and debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs for [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) tell you right at the top, this is a very low-level library, meant primarily to support [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), and:

> See also [The Requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/) is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

If you can `conda install requests` or `pip install requests`, your problem becomes trivial:

```
import requests
req = requests.get('https://www.worldcubeassociation.org/results/events.php?eventId=222&regionId=&years=&show=All%2BPersons&average=Average')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
```

If you can't install a third-party library, working around this is *possible*, but not actually supported, and not easy. None of the chunk-handling code in `http.client` is public or documented, but the docs do link you to [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/http/client.py#L217), where you can see the private methods. In particular, notice that `read` calls a method named `_readall_chunked`, which loops over calling a `_safe_read` method on `_get_chunk_left`. That `_safe_read` method is the code you'll need to replace (e.g., by subclassing `HTTPResponse`, or monkeypatching it) to work around this problem. Which probably isn't going to be nearly as easy or fun as just using a higher-level library.